# Remove active and focus from element on second click

Tags: css

I'm trying to make an interactive map with information on it. When you click on a dot it is resized and shows some contacts. This is achieved because the element gets the `:active` and `:focus` pseudo-classes.

Is there any way to remove the pseudo-classes from the element when it is clicked a second time? In effect, is it possible make element close when it is clicked again?

```css
.distribution-map {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.distribution-map .map-point {
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  top: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.distribution-map .map-point:active,
.distribution-map .map-point:focus {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  filter: opacity: 1;
  width: 300px;
  height: 220px;
  color: #e5e5e5;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, width 0.25s ease-in-out, height 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, width 0.25s ease-in-out, height 0.25s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="distribution-map">
  <button class="map-point">
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### This can be achieved with `pointer-events: none;`

By adding `pointer-events: none;` to the focused element you can stop mouse interaction on the element so effectively it becomes unfocused on the next click.

The following modifications are required:

- Add `pointer-events: none;` to `.distribution-map .map-point:active, .distribution-map .map-point:focus`

```css
.distribution-map {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.distribution-map .map-point {
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  top: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.distribution-map .map-point:active,
.distribution-map .map-point:focus {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  filter: opacity: 1;
  width: 300px;
  height: 220px;
  color: #e5e5e5;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, width 0.25s ease-in-out, height 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, width 0.25s ease-in-out, height 0.25s ease-in-out;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="distribution-map">
  <button class="map-point">
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: The issue with this though is that any events tied to the button do not seem to trigger anymore :(