# How to lose focus hyperlink when second click in CSS

Tags: css

How to make second click lose the focus function using pure css when click the hyperlink. I try using this [Remove active and focus from element on second click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39528004/remove-active-and-focus-from-element-on-second-click) also don't work for me.

image link before click: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzEnE.png)

image after click and second click:[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSCrk.png)

```
.widgettitle a::before {
content: "> ";
    font-size:16px;
}

.widgettitle a:active::before, 
.widgettitle a:focus::before 
{
content: "∨ ";
font-size:16px;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: it only will change, when click other hyperlink

Answer (score 0):

By default, only field and form elements can be focused, so depending on what type of element `.widgettitle` is, it may never match the `:focus` selector. You can add a tabindex to the element to enable it.

`<div class="widgettitle" tabindex="0">title</div>`

[Here's some more information.](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/focus/#article-header-id-0)

Hope that was helpful!